# Modeling a feature occuring more than once in obervations

Tags: feature-selection

A multiclass problem. One of the features can occur once or more than once in each observation. Can you advise on how can we model this?
eg: Predicting SAT score based on all the school(s) a student studied. A student could have studied in just one school or multiple schools.

Comment: Please give an example of such data. Without such details, I do not see how one could answer the question.

Comment: Thanks added an example

Comment: You could add an indicator variable for each school and use those as covariates.